# Does homebrew 0.9.5 really support custom repositories?

Tags: git, homebrew

Why is it that when I try to install a custom tap with homebrew it thinks I'm installing it from github?

I'm running the command:

```
$ brew tap bitcycle/internal https://github.corp.net/bitcycle/homebrew-internal
==> Tapping bitcycle/internal
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/bitcycle/homebrew-internal'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/bitcycle/homebrew-internal/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

Here's the line from `/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/tap.rb`:

```
14   def install_tap user, repo
15     # we special case homebrew so users don't have to shift in a terminal
16     repouser = if user == "homebrew" then "Homebrew" else user end
17     user = "homebrew" if user == "Homebrew"
18
19     # we downcase to avoid case-insensitive filesystem issues
20     tapd = HOMEBREW_LIBRARY/"Taps/#{user.downcase}/homebrew-#{repo.downcase}"
21     return false if tapd.directory?
22     ohai "Tapping #{repouser}/#{repo}"
23     abort unless system "git", "clone", "https://github.com/#{repouser}/homebrew-#{repo}", tapd.to_s
24
25     files = []
26     tapd.find_formula { |file| files << file }
```

Line 23 seems to indicate that the repo can never *not* be a github repo.  Command `brew --version` says that I'm running 0.9.5 on Mac OS 10.10.3.   In addition, I've read that brew any-tap was merged into brew, but I can't seem to locate the release.

Can someone help me get this working?

Comment: Well, that answers my own question.  I'm not running the one from github, I've got something older which doesn't seem to support [clone_target](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/a6fc881204171f8a230ac0a09796c49831d06c10/Library/Homebrew/cmd/tap.rb#L19).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commit/d869e887a230832326deae08a2ba451280380a7e#diff-71e5a9120ab2d059162b6b7484cb3661) that fixes this problem.  I just have an older version of Homebrew -- and versioning in Homebrew is *special*.  :)

[image: the commit that fixes it]